# Converting a dataframe to an edgelist

Tags: r, igraph

I'm trying to make an adjacency matrix or edgelist from some presence/absence data in R. I have a very large dataframe (~12k obs of 196 variables) that looks a bit like this:

```
test_input<-data.frame(sample_ID=c("samp1","samp2","samp3","samp4","samp5","samp6","samp7"),
                       sp1 = c(1,0,0,1,1,0,1),
                       sp2 = c(1,0,0,1,1,1,1),
                       sp3 = c(0,1,1,0,0,0,1),
                       sp4 = c(0,1,1,0,0,1,0), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
> test_input
  sample_ID sp1 sp2 sp3 sp4
1     samp1   1   1   0   0
2     samp2   0   0   1   1
3     samp3   0   0   1   1
4     samp4   1   1   0   0
5     samp5   1   1   0   0
6     samp6   0   1   0   1
7     samp7   1   1   1   0
```

and I'm aiming to get something like this:

```
> test_output
  col1 col2 freq
1  sp1  sp2    4
2  sp3  sp4    2
3  sp2  sp4    1
4  sp1  sp3    1
5  sp2  sp3    1
```

I've seen some nested for loop approaches [like the one here](https://github.com/ryanjw/co-occurrence/blob/master/pairwise_co-occurrence.R) but for the dataframe I have these are incredibly slow (days/weeks to run) and produce a dataframe of every possible presence/absence by every sample.

Any suggestions for how I might go about this? Preferably in a vectorised/tidyverse type way.

Thanks!

Comment: `reshape2::melt(crossprod(as.matrix(test_input[-1])))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this method with `combn`; take 2-combinations of all the `sp` columns and calcuate their inner product, which gives the frequency of co-occurrence:

```
names <- combn(names(test_input[-1]), 2)
freq <- combn(test_input[-1], 2, function(x) sum(x[1] * x[2]))

data.frame(col1 = names[1,], col2 = names[2,], freq = freq)

#  col1 col2 freq
#1  sp1  sp2    4
#2  sp1  sp3    1
#3  sp1  sp4    0
#4  sp2  sp3    1
#5  sp2  sp4    1
#6  sp3  sp4    2
```

<sub>Note: this includes pairs that occurred zero times together, filter them out if you don't need them.</sub>